# HighLight matched content after applying regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex, xml, highlight

I have to read from an xml file and apply pattern to content using regular expression in java. I want to highlight the text matched in xml file.
Can some one let me know how this can be achieved?

Sample Input xml:

```
<Message>
  <MessageID>1</MessageID>
  <User>AS</User>
  <Content>Hi this is the input message content.Pattern should be away</Content>
</Message>
```

Java code:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("away");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("input");
matcher.find();
```

If match i want to highlight the content.

Comment: What you have done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

use the replace function of java.lang.string

input = input.replace("item","hightLight tag"+item+"hightLight tag");